# How do I set up three monitors with 2x Nvidia NVS 300?

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors

I have got triple monitor setup, with two Nvidia graphics adapters. I wanted to set it up the same way as it is configured when I run Ubuntu under VMware - e.g. each screen allows to separately maximize one application. At the moment I am only able to configure the screens so they are all white, and when I move cursor it changes into black cross. Below is my setup - there is only single screen per adapter is configured right now (to nail down the problem - on single adapter with two monitors I am able to enable Twinview, but it is not what I am looking for). I know that Ubuntu is completely fine working with 3 screens, because I have it running in VM on the same setup. I just do not know how to make it run on real hw. Please, help, I do not want to run Windows + VM just to run Ubuntu with multiple screens.

---

```
    $ lspci | grep VGA
    04:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [NVS 300] (rev a2)
    05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [NVS 300] (rev a2)
```

---

```
    $ sudo lshw -C video
    [sudo] password for kpalczynski: 
      *-display               
           description: VGA compatible controller
           product: GT218 [NVS 300]
           vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
           physical id: 0
           bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
           version: a2
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
           configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
           resources: irq:32 memory:cc000000-ccffffff memory:d0000000-d3ffffff memory:d4000000-d5ffffff ioport:c000(size=128) memory:cd000000-cd07ffff
      *-display
           description: VGA compatible controller
           product: GT218 [NVS 300]
           vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
           physical id: 0
           bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
           version: a2
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
           configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
           resources: irq:40 memory:ce000000-ceffffff memory:d8000000-dbffffff memory:dc000000-ddffffff ioport:d000(size=128) memory:cf000000-cf07ffff
    kpalczynski@aam05:~$ sudo lshw -C video
      *-display               
           description: VGA compatible controller
           product: GT218 [NVS 300]
           vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
           physical id: 0
           bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
           version: a2
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
           configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
           resources: irq:32 memory:cc000000-ccffffff memory:d0000000-d3ffffff memory:d4000000-d5ffffff ioport:c000(size=128) memory:cd000000-cd07ffff
      *-display
           description: VGA compatible controller
           product: GT218 [NVS 300]
           vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
           physical id: 0
           bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
           version: a2
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
           configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
           resources: irq:40 memory:ce000000-ceffffff memory:d8000000-dbffffff memory:dc000000-ddffffff ioport:d000(size=128) memory:cf000000-cf07ffff
```

---

```
    xrandr -q
    xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
    Screen 0: minimum 320 x 175, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
    default connected 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
       1920x1080      50.0     51.0* 
       1680x1050      52.0     53.0  
       1600x1024      54.0  
       1440x900       55.0  
       1400x1050      56.0     57.0     58.0  
       1360x768       59.0     60.0  
       1280x1024      61.0     62.0     63.0  
       1280x960       64.0     65.0  
       1152x864       66.0     67.0     68.0     69.0     70.0     71.0     72.0  
       1024x768       73.0     74.0     75.0     76.0     77.0     78.0  
       960x720        79.0     80.0  
       960x600        81.0  
       960x540        82.0  
       928x696        83.0     84.0  
       896x672        85.0     86.0  
       840x525        87.0     88.0     89.0     90.0     91.0  
       832x624        92.0  
       800x600        93.0     94.0     95.0     96.0     97.0     98.0     99.0    100.0    101.0    102.0  
       800x512       103.0  
       720x450       104.0  
       720x400       105.0  
       700x525       106.0    107.0    108.0    109.0  
       680x384       110.0    111.0  
       640x512       112.0    113.0    114.0  
       640x480       115.0    116.0    117.0    118.0    119.0    120.0    121.0  
       640x400       122.0  
       640x350       123.0  
       576x432       124.0    125.0    126.0    127.0    128.0    129.0    130.0  
       512x384       131.0    132.0    133.0    134.0    135.0  
       416x312       136.0  
       400x300       137.0    138.0    139.0    140.0    141.0  
       360x200       142.0  
       320x240       143.0    144.0    145.0    146.0  
       320x200       147.0  
       320x175       148.0
```

---

```
    $ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf
    # nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
    # nvidia-settings:  version 295.33  (buildd@allspice)  Fri Mar 30 15:25:24 UTC 2012

    Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier     "Layout0"
        Screen      0  "Screen0" 1920 0
        Screen      1  "Screen1" LeftOf "Screen0"
        InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
        InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
        Option         "Xinerama" "0"
    EndSection

    Section "Files"
    EndSection

    Section "InputDevice"
        # generated from default
        Identifier     "Mouse0"
        Driver         "mouse"
        Option         "Protocol" "auto"
        Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
        Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
        Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
    EndSection

    Section "InputDevice"
        # generated from default
        Identifier     "Keyboard0"
        Driver         "kbd"
    EndSection

    Section "Monitor"
        # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
        Identifier     "Monitor0"
        VendorName     "Unknown"
        ModelName      "DELL U2312HM"
        HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
        VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
        Option         "DPMS"
    EndSection

    Section "Monitor"
        # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
        Identifier     "Monitor1"
        VendorName     "Unknown"
        ModelName      "DELL U2312HM"
        HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
        VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
        Option         "DPMS"
    EndSection

    Section "Device"
        Identifier     "Device0"
        Driver         "nvidia"
        VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
        BoardName      "NVS 300"
        BusID          "PCI:5:0:0"
    EndSection

    Section "Device"
        Identifier     "Device1"
        Driver         "nvidia"
        VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
        BoardName      "NVS 300"
        BusID          "PCI:4:0:0"
    EndSection

    Section "Screen"
        Identifier     "Screen0"
        Device         "Device0"
        Monitor        "Monitor0"
        DefaultDepth    24
        Option         "TwinView" "0"
        Option         "TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
        Option         "metamodes" "DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; DFP-0: 1920x1080_60_0 +0+0"
        SubSection     "Display"
            Depth       24
        EndSubSection
    EndSection

    Section "Screen"
        Identifier     "Screen1"
        Device         "Device1"
        Monitor        "Monitor1"
        DefaultDepth    24
        Option         "TwinView" "0"
        Option         "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
        SubSection     "Display"
            Depth       24
        EndSubSection
    EndSection
```

---

Answer (score 1):

This might be relevant - I have noticed that xrandr output is completely missing information about other outputs, even the one that is currently configured?